# Angular2: Disabled Form Control's values not found in FormGroup.value

Tags: angular

I have:

```
this.editMemberForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: [{value: '', disabled: true}],
  id: [{value: '', disabled: true}],
  relType: ''
});
```

Then I set values to the disabled form controls:

```
this.editMemberForm.patchValue({
  name: 'Me',
  id: '000',
});
```

And in `onSubmit()`:

```
console.log('Saving data', this.editMemberForm.value);
// { relType: '123' }
```

I need `this.editMemberForm.value` to be `{ name: "Me", id: '000', relType: "123" }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [getRawValue()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#getRawValue-anchor) to get disabled controls values back as well.