# How to access the value of an input disabled?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm creating a reactive form in angular 2 and using material angular 2 to inputs;

I need to set an input as disabled and when submitting the value that is in the unlocked input the value to be sent. I Already created the input and the disabled is running. My problem is that when I give a submit value it does not come.

My code

```
this.formVariacao = this._fb.group({

   id:[p && p['id']],
   codigoItem: [p && p['codigoItem'], Validators.required],
});
```

My html

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Código da Variação" formControlName="codigoItem" name="codigoItem">
</md-input-container>
```

I block the input as follows

```
this.formVariacao.get('codigoItem').disable();
```

Only when I send the form the value does not come. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Disabled Form Control's values not found in FormGroup.value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42452776/angular2-disabled-form-controls-values-not-found-in-formgroup-value)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As you noticed Angular ignores disabled form controls in the form object.

This can be easily fixed by using `getRawValue()`, which includes **all** form controls, disabled or not. So for example on your submit, you pass the form (NOT the form value) like so:

```
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formVariacao)"
```

Then you can use `getRawValue`:

```
onSubmit(form) {
  console.log(form.getRawValue())
}
```

Comment: Is there also some kind of subscription that provides the same functionality as `valueChanges` but for the raw value? I've been looking for a while but can't find something that provides this as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

From the code docs :

```
 /**
     * A control is `disabled` when its `status === DISABLED`.
     *
     * Disabled controls are exempt from validation checks and
     * are not included in the aggregate value of their ancestor
     * controls.
     */
```

So if you're using `disable()` only to make the control to have `disabled` attribute, don't use `disable()`, use `[attr.disbaled]="yourVariable"`

LIke this :

```
<input [attr.disabled]="disabled" mdInput placeholder="Código da Variação" formControlName="codigoItem" name="codigoItem">
```

and then in your typescript :

instead of

```
 this.formVariacao.get('codigoItem').disable();
```

Do this :

```
  private disabled = false;



  this.disabled = true;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But how could I use it in a reactive form? I am disabled using typescript.

Comment: this problem with this approach is that HTML sees both disabled="false" and disabled="true" as "disabled"

Comment: and the solution, apparently is: `[attr.disabled]="disabled || null"`